# the import java.time cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Hello I am using eclipse Mars and I have the following message error generated :

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems
The import java.time cannot be resolved
LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a type
LocalDateTime cannot be resolved
```

I just would like to solve the problem I think I should use JDK 8 but i don't know to use it in eclipse.

Comment: You'll want to set Eclipse's java compiler level to 1.8. Go into preferences, java, compiler, and you'll see the settings there.

Comment: I've done  that stuff the problem is I don't have LocalDateTime in my library java.time

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Build `automatically` is checked and Clean. If it doesn't work, restart Eclipse and do again.